# Making 4-gram data by shifting 2 units of data at a time

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I have a sequence of data that I wish to build n-grams from it. An excerpt of a sequence look is as follows. 
`8c b0 00 f0 05 fc 04 46 00 f0 fe fb 40 f2 00 05 c2 f2 00 05 28 78 00` I currently uses ntlk's `ngrams()` function to build 4-grams from this data as 
`8c b0 00 f0`, `b0 00 f0 05`,`00 f0 05 fc`...etc. which is just creating 4-grams by sliding one by one. However, my requirement is instead of sliding one by one, I need to slide two by two, while creating the n-grams. So the expected out `8c b0 00 f0`, `00 f0 05 fc`,`05 fc 04 46`...etc. I searched but could not find any way to do this instead of shifting one by one as I currently have. following is a part of the 4 line code that emphasis the current work

```py
 s = finalString.lower()
 s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', s)
 tokens = [token for token in s.split(" ") if token != ""]
 output = list(ngrams(tokens, 4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following trick,

```
s = '8c b0 00 f0 05 fc 04 46 00 f0 fe fb 40 f2 00 05 c2 f2 00 05 28 78 00'

from nltk import ngrams
output = list(ngrams(s.split(), 4))[::2]     # Using only alternate records from ngrams,
                                             # Here 2 is the sliding window that you want.
```

### Output:

```
[('8c', 'b0', '00', 'f0'), ('00', 'f0', '05', 'fc'), ('05', 'fc', '04', '46'), ('04', '46', '00', 'f0'), ('00', 'f0', 'fe', 'fb'), ('fe', 'fb', '40', 'f2'), ('40', 'f2', '00', '05'), ('00', '05', 'c2', 'f2'), ('c2', 'f2', '00', '05'), ('00', '05', '28', '78')]
```

Comment: Instead of the list comprehension, do this instead `list(ngrams(s.split(), 4))[::2]`

Comment: @alvas, Thank you for the input. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

```
tokens = [token for token in s.split(" ") if token != ""]
```

This can be shortened, since `.split()` splits on spaces by default (and you already replaced the rest with spaces anyway) and it won't return `''`, since any length of white space will cause only a single split.

So: `'ab    12 23'.split() == ['ab', '12', '23']`

`ngrams()` from `nltk` creates n-grams from whatever iterable it is given, but you're really looking for flattened 2-grams of pairs of values from the iterable.

```
from nltk.util import ngrams

s = '8c b0 00 f0 05 fc 04 46 00 f0 fe fb 40 f2 00 05 c2 f2 00 05 28 78 00'

parts = iter(s.split())
result = [(*t[0], *t[1]) for t in ngrams(zip(parts, parts), 2)]

print(result)
```

The expression `(*t[0], *t[1])` just takes the two tuple parts of the 2-tuple `t` and puts their parts into a new tuple. It does so for each tuple `t` in the n-grams generated from `zip(parts, parts)`, which creates pairs from a single iterator over the split parts of `s`.

This also avoids generating all the ngrams and then discarding the ones you don't need.

An even nicer, but only slightly different solution:

```
parts = iter(s.split())
result = ((*t[0], *t[1]) for t in ngrams(zip(parts, parts), 2))

print(list(result))
```

Note the parentheses instead of the brackets, this causes `result` to be a generator instead of a list. This way, even if `s` would be a really long or even infinite series of values, you'd still be able to get 2-step 4-grams from `result` as often as you like. This makes a lot of sense, as `ngrams()` itself also returns an iterator instead of a pre-generated list.